# usage of ajax-contact-form for file type HTML Forms

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I have a such form:

```
<form id ="ajax-contact-form" action="upload.php" method = "post">

                <div class="col1">

                  <div class="clear"></div>
                  <br><br>
                  <INPUT type="text" name="Name" value="Full name:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Full name:'" 
                            onFocus="if(this.value =='Full name:' ) this.value=''">
                  <div class="clear"></div>

                  <INPUT type="text" name="Email" value="Your email:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Your email:'" 
                            onFocus="if(this.value =='Your email:' ) this.value=''"><div class="clear"></div>

                  <INPUT type="text" name="University" value="University, College or Institute:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='University, College or Institute:'" 
                            onFocus="if(this.value =='University, College or Institute:' ) this.value=''">
                  <div class="clear"></div></div>

                  <div class="col1 pad_left5"><br>
                  <h4>Please write about your academic research experiences:</h4>
                  <TEXTAREA NAME="Content" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value=''" 
                          onFocus="if(this.value =='' ) this.value=''"></TEXTAREA>
                  <div class="clear"></div></div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>


                  <br><h4>Upload your photo (200 x 200):</h4><br>
                  <INPUT type = "file" name="Picture" id = "picture" lang="en">
                  <div class="clear"></div><br>

                  <h4>Please upload your academic publications under one folder as a compressed file:</h4><br>
                  <INPUT type = "file" name="Publications" id = "Publication" lang="en">
                  <div class="clear"></div><br>

                  <div class="box">
                  <div class="services1">
                  <h4>GPA</h4><br>
                  <INPUT class="capthca" type="text" name="GPA" value="GPA:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='GPA:'" 
                            onFocus="if(this.value =='GPA:' ) this.value=''">

                  <div class="clear"></div><br>

                  <h4>IELTS</h4><br>
                  <INPUT class="capthca" type="text" name="IELTS" value="IELTS Score:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='IELTS Score:'" 
                            onFocus="if(this.value =='IELTS Score:' ) this.value=''">
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="services1">
                  <h4>TOEFL</h4><br>
                  <INPUT class="capthca" type="text" name="PBT" value="PBT:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='PBT:'" 
                            onFocus="if(this.value =='PBT:' ) this.value=''"> <div class="clear"></div>

                  <INPUT class="capthca" type="text" name="CBT" value="CBT:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='CBT:'" 
                            onFocus="if(this.value =='CBT:' ) this.value=''"> <div class="clear"></div>

                  <INPUT class="capthca" type="text" name="IBT" value="IBT:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='IBT:'" 
                            onFocus="if(this.value =='IBT:' ) this.value=''"> <div class="clear"></div>


                  <div class="clear"></div> 
                  </div>

                  <div class="services1 last">
                  <h4>ALES</h4><br>
                  <INPUT class="capthca" type="text" name="VERBAL" value="Verbal Score:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Verbal Score:'" 
                            onFocus="if(this.value =='Verbal Score:' ) this.value=''"> <div class="clear"></div>

                  <INPUT class="capthca" type="text" name="MATH" value="Math Score:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Math Score:'" 
                            onFocus="if(this.value =='Math Score:' ) this.value=''"> <div class="clear"></div>

                  <INPUT class="capthca" type="text" name="EQUALWEIGHT" value="Equal Weight Score:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Equal Weight Score:'" 
                            onFocus="if(this.value =='Equal Weight Score:' ) this.value=''"> <div class="clear"></div>
                  </div>          
                  <div class="clear"></div> 
                  </div>     
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                  <INPUT class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                  <div class="clear"></div>  


                  <?php
                  $Name = $_POST["Name"];
                  $University = $_POST["University"];
                  $Academic_Experience = $_POST["Content"];
                  $Photo = $_POST["Picture"];
                  $Publications = $_POST["Publications"];
                  $GPA = (float)$_POST["GPA"];
                  $VERBAL = (float)$_POST["VERBAL"];
                  $MATH = (float)$_POST["MATH"];
                  $EQUALWEIGHT = (float)$_POST["EQUALWEIGHT"];
                  $PBT = (float)$_POST["PBT"];
                  $CBT = (float)$_POST["CBT"];
                  $IBT = (float)$_POST["IBT"];
                  $IELTS = (float)$_POST["IELTS"];
                  ?>
                  </form>
```

When I run this code, the submit doesn't work. But when I remove 'id="ajax-contact-form", the submit works. But I want to design my form in the style of ajax-contact-form. How can I solve the problem? Probably ajax-contact-form doesn't work because of that it involves file type inputs. But I really need such type of input, and want the design of ajax-contact-from. I'm waiting for your help. Thank you...

Comment: Hello Hasan, same problem eh? Seeing that the word `ajax` appears, it may help others if you were to include your full code for all files. I take it that you have a seperate Ajax file, so please post all relevant code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sLKSf0ST via this link, you can reach the css code that ajax contact form has been created. You can find it under the title of "=====Contacts====="

Comment: That's a lot of CSS. The only thing I can think of, that could cause this problem, is the potential mispelled word `capthca` which I originally saw in your very first question. Maybe you did mispell it and needs to be `captcha`? I say this because, that is what that code is called http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA that's the best I can say. Try to build another stylesheet instead, and start anew.

Comment: captcha is not the problem. Because at first I have created a contact form which involves captcha. And the size of captcha bar is appropriate for my entries under the form. It is just a name. I just tried to modify the captcha type input for some entries. If it would cause a problem, when I remove "id="ajax-contact-form", it wouldn't work. But when I remove it, the SUBMIT works. And there is no problem with captcha at that time.

Comment: Now I have removed upload file type and tried again, it still doesn't work. I think you may be right about captcha type. I'm trying now.

Comment: My guess is then, that your image button that you have for it, is not properly aligned and is not clickable in the region it has been assigned. This I have seen before and it happened to me once also. I suggest you look through all instances of `#ajax-contact-form` in your CSS and play around with the pixel widths etc. I can't modify/test your code, because I stand at spending a minimum of an hour and I have work to do myself ;-)) that's what I think is happening, and I sincerely hope you find the attribute that is causing this. Cheers

Comment: You're welcome Hasan. Keep me posted if you are successful by adding `@` followed by my name. I would be curious to know what the problem was.

Comment: It seems like you fixed your problem, from what I could tell by your new question.